# Disable Family Sharing for Apple TV+

Tags: itunes, ipad, appletv

I used family sharing for my family, now I have Apple TV+ and suddenly lot's of content is enabled for my daughter to watch on her IPad that I would rather not share with her.

Thus, is there a possibility to disable family sharing vor Apple TV+ specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you’re using parental controls on your child’s iPad, you can disable access to video content with the ratings of your choice. See [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304#explicit-content) for Apple’s instructions on how to do so.

The current instructions (which may change, so following the link is preferable) are:

> To restrict explicit content and content ratings:
>
> 1. Go to Settings and tap Screen Time.
> 2. Tap Content & Privacy Restrictions, then tap Content  Restrictions.
> 3. Choose the settings you want for each feature or setting under Allowed Store Content.

Comment: thanks, I new about that option but I find that level of control rather coarse. Anyway, it seems to be the only option available other than removing my kid's account from the family sharing.